# print text whitout dialog in java

Tags: java, printing

I need your help.
I need to print from java, live my default printer.
I do it with Printable

```
PrinterJob PrinterJob.getPrinterJob job = ();
Printservice Printservice = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService ();
```

My problem is, I need not appear dialogue (PrintDialog) to print directly without question.

```
if (job.printDialog ()) {
plpt1.setTexto ("Garcia", true, 50);
job.setPrintable (plpt1);}
```

can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Why can't you remove the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that without the conditional, you should get the desired result:

```
plpt1.setTexto ("Garcia", true, 50);
job.setPrintable (plpt1);
```

Comment: perfect, he had tried that, and not printed. But the printer had been locked.

One more question.

I have to print a series of strings, similar to the attached image.
The problem I have, is not the right way to do it.

Serious parts.
string1
-------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------
string2
-------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------
string3

String4 ...

Thank you

https://www.dropbox.com/s/weotwnu4hnoxhxt/print.jpg?dl=0